# asp.net Chart Controls on a user control in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, charts

I am new to the MVC Framework. Im working on a dashboard project in the MVC framework. The project consists of a bunch of charting control in a user controls contained in a master page. I did a test on a charting control on a aspx page..and it works...but when I moved the code to a ascx (usercontrol)  the chart doesnt render. Any ideas?!?!?!...I'm stuck. Thanks in advance

Jeff

Code that is in in the .aspx

```
 <%
  System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart Chart1 = new System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();
  Chart1.Width = 450;
  Chart1.Height = 296;
  Chart1.RenderType = RenderType.ImageTag;
  Chart1.ImageLocation = "..\\..\\TempImages\\ChartPic_#SEQ(200,30)";

  Chart1.Palette = ChartColorPalette.BrightPastel;
                    Title t = new Title("Program Pipeline", Docking.Top, new System.Drawing.Font("Trebuchet MS", 14, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold), System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(26, 59, 105));
                    Chart1.Titles.Add(t);
                    Chart1.ChartAreas.Add("Prog 1");

  // create a couple of series
                    Chart1.Series.Add("Backlog");
                    Chart1.Series.Add("Constructed");
                    Chart1.Series.Add("Billed");
                    Chart1.Series.Add("BudgetUsed");
                    Chart1.Series.Add("Total");



                    Chart1.Series["Backlog"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedBar100;
                    Chart1.Series["Constructed"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedBar100;
                    Chart1.Series["Billed"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedBar100;
                    Chart1.Series["Total"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedBar100;
                    Chart1.Series["BudgetUsed"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedBar100;

                    Chart1.Series["Backlog"]["DrawingStyle"] = "Cylinder";
                    Chart1.Series["Constructed"]["DrawingStyle"] = "Cylinder";
                    Chart1.Series["Billed"]["DrawingStyle"] = "Cylinder";
                    Chart1.Series["BudgetUsed"]["DrawingStyle"] = "Cylinder";
                    Chart1.Series["Total"]["DrawingStyle"] = "Cylinder";


                    // Bar Size
                    Chart1.Series["Backlog"]["PointWidth"] = "0.6";
                    Chart1.Series["Constructed"]["PointWidth"] = "0.6";
                    Chart1.Series["Billed"]["PointWidth"] = "0.6";
                    Chart1.Series["BudgetUsed"]["PointWidth"] = "0.6";
                    Chart1.Series["Total"]["PointWidth"] = "0.6";




                    int _total = 0;
                    int _newTotalAmt = 100 - _total;
                    foreach (MvcApplication1.Models.Amount obj in Model.GetTotalAmt("plm1"))
                    {
                        _total += obj.TotalAmount;

                        Chart1.Series[obj.PLMType].Points.AddY(obj.TotalAmount);
                    }
                    Chart1.Series["BudgetUsed"].Points.AddY(0);
                    Chart1.Series["Total"].Points.AddY(_newTotalAmt);



                    _total = 0;
                    _newTotalAmt = 100 - _total;
                    foreach (MvcApplication1.Models.Amount obj in Model.GetTotalAmtForPLM2("plm2"))
                    {
                        _total += obj.TotalAmount;

                        Chart1.Series[obj.PLMType].Points.AddY(obj.TotalAmount);
                    }
                    Chart1.Series["BudgetUsed"].Points.AddY(0);
                    Chart1.Series["Total"].Points.AddY(_newTotalAmt);




                    _total = 0;
                    _newTotalAmt = 100 - _total;
                    foreach (MvcApplication1.Models.Amount obj in Model.GetTotalAmt("plm3"))
                    {
                        _total += obj.TotalAmount;

                        Chart1.Series[obj.PLMType].Points.AddY(obj.TotalAmount);
                    }
                    Chart1.Series["BudgetUsed"].Points.AddY(0);
                    Chart1.Series["Total"].Points.AddY(_newTotalAmt);



                  // MvcApplication1.Models.TotalPOAmount oTotal = Model.GetOverAllBudget();



                    // add points to series 3
                    Chart1.Series["Billed"].Points.AddY(0);
                    Chart1.Series["Constructed"].Points.AddY(0);
                    Chart1.Series["Backlog"].Points.AddY(0);
                    Chart1.Series["BudgetUsed"].Points.AddY(39);
                    Chart1.Series["Total"].Points.AddY(100);



  Chart1.BorderSkin.SkinStyle = BorderSkinStyle.Emboss;
  Chart1.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(26, 59, 105);
                    Chart1.BorderlineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;
  Chart1.BorderWidth = 2;

                    Chart1.Legends.Add("Legend");

      // show legend based on check box value
                  //  Chart1.Legends["Legend1"].Enabled = ShowLegend.Checked;

  // Render chart control
  Chart1.Page = this;
  HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(Page.Response.Output);
  Chart1.RenderControl(writer);


                    //IList<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
                    //SelectListItem sli = new SelectListItem();
                    //sli.Text = "test1";
                    //sli.Value = "1";

                    //list.Add(sli);
                    //ViewData["Test"] = list;


                 %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had exactly the same issue. My problem was to do with the paths to the image file. The chart control was getting it wrong when placed on a usercontrol. If I changed the chart to use Imagestoragemode of HttpHandler then it worked as intended.

unfortunatly this stopped me being able to unit test my views. In the end I put the chart control on an aspx page & then used jQuery to load it when needed. (Luckily my dashboard page used javascript to load the contents of the portlets)

Answer (score 1):

I've just been trying to get round what seems to be the same problem. When I moved the code (similar to yours above) to a UserControl the **System.Web.UI.DataVisualization** namespace wasn't recognised and I received the error:

> The type or namespace name
>   'DataVisualization' does not exist in
>   the namespace 'System.Web.UI' (are you
>   missing an assembly reference?)

The namespace only seemed to be recognised when the Chart code lay within an asp control (in the aspx page it was within an **<asp:Content>** control). So I put the Chart code within an **<asp:Panel>** control and it worked.